# How can I tell that a given cocycle represents an element of the cohomology group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question

http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html

On page 208 example 3.8 in Hatcher, we are calculating the cohomology groups of a genus 4 non-orientable surface.

Hatcher makes the arguement that using the universal coefficient theorem, it is easy to find a basis for $H^1(N)$, we just dualize the basis for $H_1(N)$. He then goes on to talk about how we need to find a cocycle to represent each element of our basis for $H^1(N)$. He gives an example of a cocycle by using a dashed line and saying let this be the homomorphism that sends each edge this line intersects to 1, and it is easy to check that it is a coycle.

My question is, how can I tell that this cocycle represents the given homology class? What are the coboundry that I am modding out by?

In general, my question is quite broad I suppose. Given a cocycle, can someone give me general insight into understanding the cohomology class it belongs to? I'm having a hard time understanding the equivalence relation imposed by the coboundaries.

Comment: and $d$ is the coboundary operator? Why must $\beta$ be a $n-1$ cocycle? Wouldn't that mean $d\beta=0$? Are you sure $\beta$ doesn't run through the $n-1$ cochains?

Comment: Sorry ! yes of course $\beta$ can be any (n-1)-form.

Comment: What I wanted to stress is that equivalence relations in vector spaces are easier to describe by "what is equivalent to 0" and then forming the equivalence class of something like $\alpha$ as things that can be written as $\alpha$ plus something equivalent to 0.